# how to build next.js files and upload to linux shared hosting

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have a project done using **next.js** and **reactjs**. I have used next.js with reactjs for **SSR**.

Now the problem is I cannot build the project. If I build (**next build**, **next export**), the generated index.html shows only the first page and other page links are not working. How to build the project and generate the files. Is it possible.

I have a **linux shared hosting**. Is **next.js** works in **linux shared hosting**. Please guide me through. I am new to **next.js**.

`package.json`

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "export": "next export",
    "start": "next start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "next": "9.1.6",
    "react": "16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "16.12.0"
  }
}
```

`next.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  exportTrailingSlash: true,
  exportPathMap: function() {
    return {
      '/': { page: '/' }
    };
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `exportPathMap` is specifically telling Next to only build the index.js file. You only need to include `exportPathMap` if you need to customize the build. If you exclude it, it will build everything in your `pages` directory. If you include it, you can merge it with the default parameter that comes into that function (which will have all those `pages` files), or you can write your own (like you have done) to tell Next exactly what to build.

So if your pages were coming from a server (like from a CMS), you would use `exportPathMap` to ping the server and tell Next what pages to build.

Comment: let me go through it